# Count the number of current posts in Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I am trying to get the number of currently displayed posts in the content area. The number of Posts currently displayed is 3 but when I check the Length, its returning 1.

```
$(document).on("click", ".load-more", function() {

    var currentPost = $('#postlist');
    loadMore = currentPost.parent().find('.load-more');
    initialPostcount = currentPost.length;
    console.log(initialPostcount);

})
```

1. Current list of Posts:

[image]

2. Inspecting element:

[image]

```
<!-- Page: Blog Posts -->
    <div id="blogposts" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h2>My Blog Posts</h2>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder='Search blog posts...' id="postlist"> </ul><!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div class="load-more">Load More Posts...</div>
        <div id='loader'><img src="css/images/loader.gif"/></div> 
    </div><!-- page -->
```

Comment: provide some sample html..or better yet a demo that replicates issue. You sound like your checking parent container not it;s children

Comment: The length of `$('#postlist')` is always either 0 or 1 because ids must be unique (and if they aren't only one of them is selected). By the way, the screenshot doesn't help. We need to see the HTML it's made with.

Comment: and what is the count of `$('#postlist DIV').length` or `$('#postlist.ui-listview').length`

Comment: Well, the HTML you're showing doesn't have any posts.

Comment: $('#postlist DIV').length is showing 6, $('#postlist.ui-listview').length is showing 1

Comment: lol sorry for that also tell me the length of `$('#postlist li').length`

Comment: Perfect, $('#postlist li').length gave me a count of 3. Exactly what I needed

Comment: Down vote on the question, is this a joke?

Comment: You never posted correct sample HTML even after prompted to do so multiple times. People are having to guess. Why shouldn't it be downvoted?

Comment: doesn't make any sense but that the HTML page - lol

Comment: No it isn't. Where are the posts?

Comment: I didn't include the whole JS page since that won't be needed. Never mind, thanks to all that down voted

Comment: You're right, that won't be needed, but the generated HTML is. You can see it if you right click on the list and select "inspect element".

Comment: That's what I expected to have been asked in the first place - lol. It won't change anything now. There is always room for improvement. If I made a mistake in my decision i would take ownership and responsibility for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posts are in `ul` list. you need to count the length of the `li`'s under this `ul#postlist` [*assuming that each `li` is a post*]

```
<ul data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder='Search blog posts...' id="postlist"> </ul><!-- content -->
```

Change your `$('#postlist')`

```
var currentPost = $('#postlist');
```

with

```
var currentPost = $('#postlist li');
```

`$('#postlist li')` is what you are looking for,